# Heroku insists on using old file name

Tags: heroku

Had a file name
`userName.js`

imported it using uppercase file name..worked ok on Mac but caused error  on Heroku.
`import {name} from 'UserName.js'`

So I renamed file.. and push it up to Heroku..

`mv userName.js UserName.js`

`git add . && git commit -m 'change file name' && git push heroku master`

Same error is occuring..
so I run bash on Heroku..

`heroku run bash
ls`

for some reason it is still on Heroku as...
`userName.js`?

I can run
`mv userName.js UserName.js` as heroku bash..
but next time I push the same `userName.js`? is back.

Comment: try copying the file, to have the two files with the different cases temporarly and then delete the old one?

Comment: gave that a try Mac sees the two as equivalent and won't let me

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

Saved the contents of `userName.js` to clipboard.
Removed the old file from git history..
`git rm --cached userName.js`
`touch UserName.js` and pasted in old contents..

after pushing up to Heroku..seems to get it right.